# Color each edge separately in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I want to color the edge AB with thick blue color and edges AC and BC with thick red color.

Referring to the answer in [Multiple color edges in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394999/multiple-color-edges-in-tikz), one way is to use the `\clip[draw]` command. But, I am not sure how to use in my context, as my shape is a triangle and the triangle is filled with orange color as well.

Expected Result:

[image]

Current Result:

[image]

The triangle should still have the orange color filled and the edges with the above mentioned color.

**Note**: This example is from the PGF manual only. Providing the code in the manual is not recommended/appreciated without explanation.

Is there an alternate way to fill a shape instead of using `\filldraw` or `\draw[fill]` command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[help lines/.style={thin,draw=black!50}]
  \coordinate[label=left:\textcolor{blue!80!black}{$A$}] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=right:\textcolor{blue!80!black}{$B$}] (B) at (1.25,0.25);
  \draw[name path=A--B] (A) -- (B);
%  \draw let \p1 = ($(B) - (A)$),
%            \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
%        in
%           (A) circle (\n2)
%           (B) circle (\n2);
  \node (D) [name path=D,draw,circle through=(B),label=left:$D$,help lines,draw] at (A) {};
  \node (E) [name path=E,draw,circle through=(A),label=right:$E$,help lines,draw] at (B) {};

  \path [name intersections={of=D and E, by={[label=above:$C$]C,[label=below:$C'$]C'}}];

  %\coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C) at (intersection-1); using by instead

  \draw [name path=C--C',red] (C) -- (C');

  \path [name intersections={of=A--B and C--C', by=F}];
  \node[fill=red,inner sep=1pt, label=-45:$F$] at (F) {};

  \draw[fill=orange!80] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
  \foreach \point in {A,B,C}
    \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (\point) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if you add `\draw [name path=A--C,thick,red] (A) -- (C) -- (B);
  \draw [name path=A--B,thick,blue] (A) -- (B);` at the end of your `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @leandriis then how do I use fill draw.  You are splitting the draw statements

Comment: In my above comment I have split up the triangle into three parts (orange triangle, red line, blue line), as you already noticed. In [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478550/color-each-edge-separately-in-tikz?noredirect=1#comment1208622_478553) I also made a suggestion on how to draw the orange filled triangle with thick red lines using a single `\draw` command. You will nevertheless need a second `\draw` command to add the thick blue line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options can be applied to a **portion of the path**, this is the case of `rounded corners`. But this does not work with the `colors` as indicated on page 149 of manual 3.1.1 which always apply to the **entire path**.

Screenshot of the page 149:

[image: screenshot]

So, to make it easier:

- I first colored the ABC triangle orange with the `\fill` command *(which doesn't draw anything)*;
- then I drew **two** paths, one in `blue`, the other in `red`.

[image: screenshot]

Commented code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[help lines/.style={thin,draw=black!50}]
  \coordinate[label=left:\textcolor{blue!80!black}{$A$}] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=right:\textcolor{blue!80!black}{$B$}] (B) at (1.25,0.25);
  \path[name path=A--B] (A) -- (B);% <-- construct the path, but not draw it
%  \draw let \p1 = ($(B) - (A)$),
%            \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
%        in
%           (A) circle (\n2)
%           (B) circle (\n2);
  \node (D) [name path=D,draw,circle through=(B),label=left:$D$,help lines,draw] at (A) {};
  \node (E) [name path=E,draw,circle through=(A),label=right:$E$,help lines,draw] at (B) {};

  \path [name intersections={of=D and E, by={[label=above:$C$]C,[label=below:$C'$]C'}}];

  %\coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C) at (intersection-1); using by instead

  \path [name path=C--C',red] (C) -- (C');

  \path [name intersections={of=A--B and C--C', by=F}];
  %\node[fill=red,inner sep=1pt, label=-45:$F$] at (F) {};

  \fill[orange!80] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;%<-- only fill without draw the edges
  \draw[blue,thick](A)--(B);%<-- draw in blue
  \draw[red,thick](A)--(C)--(B);%<-- draw in red
  \foreach \point in {A,B,C}
    \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (\point) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save some of your paths by using the possibilities of the `\path` or `\draw` command. Especially the empty paths may be removed by integrating the intersections into the relevant paths.

To color your way from `A` to `B` simply draw a line between the two points (after drawing the frame or simply removing the frame). The same works for `A--B--C`.

[image: triangle]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[help lines/.style={thin,draw=black!50}]
  \path[name path=A--B] (0,0) coordinate[label=left:\textcolor{blue!80!black}{$A$}] (A) --
    (1.25,0.25) coordinate[label=right:\textcolor{blue!80!black}{$B$}] (B);
  \node (D) [name path=D,draw,circle through=(B),label=left:$D$,help lines,draw] at (A) {};
  \node (E) [name path=E,draw,circle through=(A),label=right:$E$,help lines,draw] at (B) {};
  \draw[name intersections={of=D and E, by={[label=above:$C$]C,[label=below:$C'$]C'}},
    name path=C--C',red] (C) -- (C');
  \node[fill=red,inner sep=1pt,name intersections={of=A--B and C--C', by=F},label=-45:$F$] at (F) {};

  \draw[draw=none,fill=orange!80] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
  \draw[blue,thick] (A) -- (B);
  \draw[red,thick] (A) -- (C) -- (B);

  \foreach \point in {A,B,C}
    \fill [black,opacity=0.5] (\point) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One could also use `\draw[fill=orange!80, draw=red,thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;` instead of `\draw[fill=orange!80] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;` and  `\draw[red,thick] (A) -- (C) -- (B);`.

Comment: @leandriis Well, it's to highlight the "color each edge separately" from the question. You are right that it is even shorter by overlaying drawn paths.

Comment: As you already suggested in your answer to '[...] save some of your paths [...]' I thought the same could also be applied to the code that is added to answer the question.

Comment: @leandriis My initial intention was to specifically remove these empty paths, but of course you are right ;)