# Changing colors of edges and vertices

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, shapes

How do I change the color of each edge of the shape within `\node[isosceles triangle]`?

What I have currently is just a regular isosceles triangle,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[isosceles triangle,
        draw,
        rotate = 90,
        fill=teal!10,
        minimum size =2cm] (T60) at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I've had no luck with changing the edge colors. I'd also like to add vertices and change the colors of the vertices, too.

Comment: `draw=<color>`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel that only works for changing the color of every edge at once. I want each edge to have a distinct color

Comment: Then you need to draw them separately. [Q478550](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478550), [Q141378](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141378) and probably a few more. With `outer sep=0pt` at the node, you can do `\draw[red](T60.corner 1)--(T60.corner 2);\draw[green](T60.corner 2)--(T60.corner 3);\draw[blue](T60.corner 3)--(T60.corner 1);`. Though, you will need think about the corners and the line cap. Maybe an arrow tip and some manual calculations can help.